# Select data from multiple single joined tables not completing

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a bout 20 tables with a naming scheme like `t00XX_b`and a corresponding `t00XX_b_results`
What I want to do is to join all those pairs and make one select over all those tables adding the data to one large table. To me logically, it should work this way:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (t0001_b AS t1
    RIGHT JOIN t0001_b_results AS t2 ON t1.IndexResult = t2.IndexResult), /*generates ~20000 rows*/
    (t0002_b AS t3
    RIGHT JOIN t0002_b_results AS t4 ON t3.IndexResult = t4.IndexResult), /*generates ~6000 rows*/
    ...
```

But as soon as I chain the tables, the query won't finish any more. If I execute the query with a single table pair, it works perfectly.

This example works fine:

```
 SELECT 
     *
 FROM
      (t0001_b AS t1
      RIGHT JOIN t0001_b_results AS t2 ON t1.IndexResult = t2.IndexResult)
```

I cannot see a mistake, but I'm as well not an expert in SQL. 
What's wrong? Is there something in a wrong order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the *logic* you want, but your query doubtfully is correct.  The commas are a `CROSS JOIN` operator that create a cartesian product.

In addition, my guess is that MySQL is going to materialize each join pair.

I can't really make a concrete suggestion without sample data and desired results, but perhaps you want this:

```
SELECT *
FROM t0001_b t1 RIGHT JOIN
     t0001_b_results t2
     ON t1.IndexResult = t2.IndexResult
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM t0002_b t3
     t0002_b_results t4
     ON t3.IndexResult = t4.IndexResult
. . .
```

Notes:

- Don't use `SELECT *`, especially for `UNION ALL` operations.  You should explicitly list the columns, particularly when the tables share column names.
- I much prefer `LEFT JOIN` to `RIGHT JOIN`.  The semantics are easier ("keep all rows in the first table")

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't know that a `,` is an actually operator. This explains a lot. With `UNION ALL` it works like a charm. I'll swap the `*` selector then too. Thanks a lot!